# Display multiple images retrieved from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to retrieve 5 images from database with the following code. How do I loop them without being inside the MySQL query itself as the code I'm currently running needs to pull a few other queries.

```
public function photoSlides($uiD)
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT image_path FROM user_uploads WHERE uid_fk = :uiD LIMIT 5");
    $sth->execute(array(':uiD' => $uiD));

    $data = $sth->fetch();
    return $data;
}
```

I'd like to know how I can display 5 while using only one html img tag as followed.

```
<img src="<?php echo $photoSlides;?>"/>
```

I cannot run it inside the query due to the page specifications. I'm currently running two queries that requires me if possible to retrieve these images the way I described. I'm unsure where to find some leads to accomplish what I described even some leads will be very helpful and appreciated.

QUESTIONS:

***Which is more stable/better, running it the way I described or having the while loop inside the query?***

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the answer, but worth a shot (not tested)

```
foreach(photoSlides($uiD) as $img_url){
echo '<img src="'.$img_url.'"/>'; //if this dont work try $img_url['image_path']
}
```